# Terminate pending Renderscript kernel

Tags: renderscript, android-renderscript

I have a Renderscript kernel to perform a long operation similar to the google sample. However, it is possible for users to cancel the request. Is there any API to terminate a pending Renderscript operation? How can i force renderscript to stop?

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicRenderScript

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct call to cancel.  It *may* work to call `.destroy()` on the RS context object which is bound to your script (the `RenderScript` object instance.)

Comment: My logic targets Neugut and above and destroy is documented to be a NOP. I tried using RenderScript.releaseAllContexts() from main thread but that just waits on a lock held by the task executing the actual script and locks up the UI until the script finishes.